# how to pass a ArrayList from Jsp to Spring (annotation base) Controllers

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, webforms

How do to pass a `ArrayList` of `Array` from Jsp to spring controller.

I want my user fill some form in which 1 object data is entered in many way.  What I want to make a list and save all the different values of that object.

Then i want to pass it to spring controller.  What is the best way for this?  Thanks.

Comment: what does your jsp look like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, Create Class and bind the this class to form so the controller will automatically receive the class.

It will look something like this.

```
 @RequestMapping(value="/submit",method = RequestMethod.POST)
      public ModelAndView addUser(@Valid MyClass myClass, BindingResult result){

}

public class MyClass{
private  List<ArrayList<Integer>> list = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>();

//getters and setters. 
}
```

hope it helps.

**Update:**

Ajax way:

JSON =   {"myClass" "list":[[1,2,3,4],[1,2,3,45],[3,5,1]]}

and the Controller itself.

```
 @RequestMapping(value="/submit",method = RequestMethod.POST)
     @ResponseBody
     public String getAjax(@RequestBody Myclass myClass){
//do something
}
```

and the use javascript to build suck JSON and send it to server using AJAX. You can validate your form before that using Javascript as well.

Comment: `@Valid MyClass class` this won't compile, `class` is a reserved keyword

Comment: hello sir, but how i pass this from jsp.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you'll be passing an HTTP request from a JSP to a Spring controller, not an array of arrays.

The form that your users fill out will have HTML form elements that will be sent to the server side as HTTP parameter name/value pairs.

The Spring controller will validate and bind the form elements into objects; you can certainly bind all those parameters into an array of arrays if you wish.